# How to make two independent lists on LaTeX

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I am relatively new to LaTeX and I am working on an article. I want to make to make two lists that have independent numbering with also a lot of text in between the list items. The desired final result is:

[image: example]

The code for this MWE is:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

     \usepackage[english]{babel}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage{amsmath}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{titlesec}
     \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
     \usepackage{chngcntr}

     \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
     \newlist{costbalance}{enumerate}
     \setlist{costabalance}[label=(\arabic*)]

     \title{Main Tile}
     \author{N.A}

     \begin{document}
     \maketitle

     \section{Section A}

     \subsection{Section A.1}
     Text

     \subsubsection{Section A.1.1}

     Beggining of First list
    \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\arabic*)]
    \item: 
    \end{enumerate*}
    \begin{equation}
     A + B= C
    \end{equation}

    \subsubsection{Section A.1.2}

     Resuming of first list
    \begin{enumerate*}[resume*] 
    \item: 
    \end{enumerate*}
    \begin{equation}
    B + C = D
   \end{equation}

   \begin{costbalance}
   \item:
   \end{costbalance}
   Beggining of second list (1): 
  \begin{equation}
   D - E = C
  \end{equation}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your `\newlist` is wrongly used (missing the number of levels), as well as optional argument and mandatory of `\setlist` switched, (and a typo too → costbalance, not costabalance)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't understand what is your problem? You seem to do what you want. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the list(s) at all. Why not using `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` alone.  (or `align` environment) -- it will resume the numbering automatically (unless not screwing up the resetting mechanism)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the error I got: "Missing number, treated as zero."

Comment: @user151562: This error message is due to the typos Christian Hupfer has pointed out in his first comment. The corrected code would be `\newlist{costbalance}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[costbalance]{label=(\arabic*)}`. However, it is still unclear, what you want to achieve with these lists.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer because the numbering of the equations is also independent of the lists within the paragraphs.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok, so how would I make two lists?

Comment: @user151562: I just don't understand the purpose of two lists here... Why `enumerate*` and `costbalance` ... What should they do? How should they be numbered?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer there are two big groups of equations. I need to have them numbered separately later for their solution. I made a very simplified scheme or what I need, actually, the text in between represents pages of paragraphs, images, etc. I need them to be numbered independently from 1... to n (last equation of both groups for which n may not have the same value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the purpose of the two lists is unclear, you could use your defined list `costbalance` which you can later resume. Additionally, you can define a second list called `secondlist` in the following MWE. The formating of both lists is basically identical, but their numberings are independent.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\newlist{costbalance}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[costbalance]{label=(\arabic*)}

\newlist{secondlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[secondlist]{label=(\arabic*)}


\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

\subsection{Section A.1}
     Text

\subsubsection{Section A.1.1}

 Begining of First list
 \begin{costbalance}
 \item:
 \end{costbalance}
 \begin{equation}
  A + B= C
 \end{equation}

\subsubsection{Section A.1.2}

 Resuming of first list
 \begin{costbalance}[resume*]
 \item:
 \end{costbalance}
 \begin{equation}
 B + C = D
 \end{equation}

 Begining of second list 
 \begin{secondlist}
 \item:
 \end{secondlist} 
 \begin{equation}
 D - E = C
 \end{equation}

 Resuming the second list:
 \begin{secondlist}[resume]
 \item:
 \end{secondlist}

  \end{document}
```

[image]